# Issue with batch file parameters

Tags: batch-file, parameters, passwords, copy, appdata

I'm trying to design a piece of software and need a batch file to help. Unfortunately its not working. It needs to copy an Appdata file to an F drive. The error message is "Invalid Parameters". The code is below.

```
@echo off
::checking password
set /p passguess=What is the password?:
if  %passguess% == 2973  goto end
::Copying...
xcopy C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default [F:\] [/Y]
timeout /t 10
goto vend
:end 
::Here if password is correct
echo You surpassed "the thing"
timeout /t 10
:vend
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" "F:\" /Y
```

The `[]` characters in command help indicate that the parameter is optional, it is not necessary to include unless necessary, and, when included, `[]` are not part of the switch.